# read dbf file from web service developed with c # using microsoft.ace12 version 64 bit

Tags: c#, web-services, oledb, dbf

I've developed a Web service in a 32-bit machine that read `dbf` files using `oledb`.

The problem is that the server is 64-bit and `oledb` was replaced by `microsoft.ace12`.

I have the following error when trying  to open a connection : `could not find isam installable.`

my connection string is :

```
connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=\\NEPTUNO\SISTEMAS\SIST\TABLAS;Exclusive=No;" providerName="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
```

any ideas?
bye ;)

Answer (score 1):

64 bit drivers will not be accessible by 32 bit applications, they are separated for a reason.

You need to rebuild the application for 64 bit platform or find a 32 bit equivalent driver.